# Why script not loading by requirejs

Tags: jquery-mobile, requirejs

I clone [this repo](https://github.com/Filirom1/jquery-mobile-backbone-requirejs.git) then put the jquery.mobile.router.js according to my folder structure. Here is my requirejs config

```
//bootstrap.js content

require.config({
    // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
    // scripts that do not call define() to register a module
    shim: {

        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: 'jquery'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        backboneLocalstorage: {
            deps: ['backbone'],
            exports: 'Store'
        },
        jQueryMobile : {
            deps:['jquery'],
            exports: "jQueryMobile"
        }
    },
    paths: {

        jquery: 'js/vendor/jquery',
        jQueryMobile: 'js/vendor/jquery.mobile.min',
        underscore: 'js/vendor/underscore.min',
        backbone: 'js/vendor/backbone',
        backboneLocalstorage: 'js/plugins/localStorage',
        text: 'js/plugins/text',
        'jquery.mobile.router': 'js/plugins/jquery.mobile.router'

}
});
```

All scripts are loading fine but the jquery.mobile.router is not loading. 
my floder structure is as bellow

```
/app
/js
  |-plugins
      |-jquery.mobile.router.js
/bootstrap.js
```

can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can put post the error message?

Comment: no error message is showing in console. i checked the path.. and the path is correct

Comment: I downloaded the repro and I was able to load everything.. So if you use, Chrome, go to 'Inspect Element" then "Network" tab, it should show you if what is loaded. Or if you use firefox, from firebug /Net, you can tell as well...

Comment: yes in repo it is working, in first line i mentioned.`I clone this repo then put the jquery.mobile.router.js according to my folder structure`. whatever i find the solution using shim config.

Comment: You can follow this repro. I use JQM router as well: https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette

Answer (score 0):

Have you call jquery.mobile.router somewhere like below

```
require(['jquery.mobile.router'], function () {
});
```